# How function template type deduction works when parameter type is const lvalue reference vs non-const lvalue refernce in c++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

```
template<typename T>
void fun(T& param) // param is a reference
{
   T abc;
   abc=1;//cannot change abc value because T is deduced as const int
//It gives compilation error because T is deduced as const int       
}

template<typename T>
void fun1(const T& param) // param is a reference
{
   T abc;
   abc=1;//can change abc value because T is deduced as int
//why T is deduced int here
}


int main()
{
int x = 2; // x is an int
const int cx = x; // cx is a const int
const int& rx = x; // rx is a reference to x as a const int
fun(x); // T is int, param's type is int&
fun(cx); // T is const int, param's type is const int&
fun(rx); // T is const int,param's type is const int&


fun1(x); // T is int, param's type is int&
fun1(cx); // T is int, param's type is const int&
fun1(rx); // T is int,param's type is const int&
return 0;
}
```

**updated**

1. Why **const int is not deduced for T in case of fun1 template function(when function template parameter type is const lvalue reference)** even `const int cx` and `const int& rx` is passed while instantiation but const int(T) type is deduced for fun(function template)?
2. Does T type deduction is depend on function template param(parameter) type.

Comment: What do you mean? Why would it be? What's the problem? Your question _"Why T is not deduced as const int in Example1 but not in Example2 when cx & rx parameter is passed to the fun function template."_ appears to be a contradiction as far as I can tell. Nothing here really makes any sense to me...

Comment: Why shouldn't it be? What's the problem?

Comment: Question is now self explanatory.

Comment: No it's not!!! Why should it be deduced any other way? What is the problem you are trying to solve??

Comment: Hi  Lightness Races in Orbit, question is updated. Please suggest if its still unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a template function like

```
template<typename T>
void fun(T & param)
```

if the parameter that is passed is actually `const`, or `volatile`, then in the template instantiation, `T` will also be "cv-qualified" appropriately.

When you put the cv-qualifier in the template function declaration, like so,

```
template<typename T>
void fun(const T & param)
```

then `T` is *not* bound as `const`. But it will be `volatile` if the parameter `volatile`.

It's actually very intuitive -- `T` is the simplest type that will make the function call work, i.e., make the expected type of the function argument match what was passed.

Similarly, if my function is

```
template <typename T>
void fun(T * param)
```

then if I pass it an `int *`, `T` will be bound as `int`.

This is described in great detail in the C++11 standard `[temp.deduct.call](14.8.2.1)`, see part three about the CV-qualifiers:

> *[temp.deduct.call] (14.8.2.1)*
>   (1) Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it P) with
>   the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it A) as described below. ... 
>   (2) If P is not a reference type:
>   (2.1) — If A is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion (4.2) is
>   used in place of A for type deduction; otherwise,
>   (2.2) — If A is a function type, the pointer type produced by the function-to-pointer standard conversion (4.3)
>   is used in place of A for type deduction; otherwise,
>   (2.3) — If A is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of A’s type are ignored for type deduction.
>   (3) If P is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of P’s type are ignored for type deduction. If P is a
>   reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction.

Answer (score 2):

Since `cx` and `rx` exhibit the same behavior here, we will use only `cx`.

`cx` is `const int`.

- case of `fun`:

`T&` matches against `const int` so `T` is deduced as `const int`, because `const` is not part of `T &`. The type of `param` is `const int&`.

- case of `fun1`:

`const T&` matches against `const int` so `T` is deduced as `int`, because `const` already is in `const T&`. The type of `param` is `const int&`.

Let's have it all visually horizontally aligned by type match, maybe this is more clear:

```
fun    param type:  | T         |  &
       receives  :  | const int |

fun1   param type:  | const | T   |  &
       receives  :  | const | int |
```

Comment: For it is very clear that it should be this way, so it is hard to understand your confusion. Thus it is difficult to find an explanation tailored for you. Fell free to ask more clarification if the current answer doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: Hi bolov, thanks for very much clear explanation. But I have one confusion why common const is get removed while type deduction of fun1

Comment: @Ajayyadav In case of fun1: it is not removed. `const` is just "outside" (not part) of `T`.

Comment: Thank you. Got it from your and crish answer. I think question is pretty much clear or any feedback to update.