# Does type deduction is failed in this example?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following example:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&) {};

int main(void){

    const int i = 0;
    const int& r = i;
    f(r); 
}
```

Let's name the template parameter type as `P` and the template argument type as `A`. Then, `P` and `A` will be:

```
P = T&, A = const int;
```

Since `P` is a reference type, [[temp.deduct.call]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-2) is not applied, but I think [[temp.deduct.call]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-3) is, which says:

> If P is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of P's type
> are ignored for type deduction. **If P is a reference type, the type
> referred to by P is used for type deduction**.

After applying the above quote, `P` and `A` will be:

```
P = T, A = const int; // T = const int;
```

I got stuck when I applied the same concept to this example:

```
template<typename T>
void g(const T&) {};

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    g(i); 
}
```

The types of the template parameter `P` and its corresponding template argument `A` are:

```
P = const T&, A = int;
```

After applying the above quote, `P` and `A` will be:

```
P = const T, A = int; // Is type deduction failed here?
```

Per my knowledge, `T` cannot be deduced because argument type `A` requires a qualification conversion to match the parameter type `P`. Am I correct to say that? if no, what's the main reason that causes deducing `const T` from `int` fails? Just if possible, provide a rule from the C++ standard for that. This is my first question.

But when I tested that code in `g++11.2.0`, the program compiles fine, and the instantiated function is `g<int>(const int&)`.

So it's seemed that the `T` has been deduced as `int`; why? this is my second question.

Comment: Is [temp.deduct.call#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-4) comes into play here?

Comment: In your template functions, maybe you'd want to `std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ < "\n";` to see what the compiler thinks.

Comment: You said "So it's seemed that..." which sounds like you weren't sure.

Comment: The ISO 14882 standard is thick reading.  You may want this interpreted into English version of template argument deduction: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Comment: @John I had a dupe(short for duplicate post) that explain exactly this. In particular, that in your 2nd example the `&` and then the `const` are stripped off. And so `T` is deduced to be `int`. I am searching for that dupe right now. That dupe which i am sure i will find after some time, explains this in detail. I will add that dupe in the dupe list when i find it.

Comment: @JasonLiam Instead of all of this why are you don't need to answer/explain the question?

Comment: @John Here because that question is a canonical question and explain the same thing in very detail. The only thing i would be doing here is repeating the exact same thing explained there. I'm still trying to find that dupe but as i've save many dupes like this so far i am not able to.

Comment: @JasonLiam In this link I gave you, this example is there: `template<typename T> void f(const T& t); bool a = false; f(a);` Now, P would be `const T` after transformation (and as the link highlight in the comments), and `A` would be `bool`; how the deduction is performed now?

Comment: @John *"T is the simplest type that will make the function call work"* from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34840884/12002570).

Comment: @John I will add an answer if i don't find that dupe later on.

Comment: @JasonLiam - Can you open the question for me to answer?

Comment: @John Yes, `temp.deduct.call#4` is used here as also given in the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) example: `template<typename T> void f(const T& t); bool a = false; f(a);` so that `P` is adjusted to `const bool` and deduced `A` is `const bool` which is more cv-qualified than `A=bool`. This is as given in the comments of cppreference.

Comment: You said *"`T` cannot be deduced because argument type A requires a qualification conversion to match the parameter type P"* which is incorrect because `int` to `const int` is not qualification conversion. Qualification conversion would be something like `int*` to `const int*`.

Comment: @JasonLiam - _if possible,_ can you answer/explain the question for me?

Answer (score 0):

Scott Meyers' Effective Modern C++ explains exactly this case in the Item 1: Understanding template type deduction, Case 1: ParamType is a Reference or Pointer, but not a Universal Reference.

Considering a code structure as below:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void f(ParamType param);

f(expr);
```

Where we want to deduce `T` and `ParamType` from `expr`.
And given the case that `ParamType` is a reference (not a universal reference; it's `const T&` in your example).
The deduction would work as:

1. If `expr`'s type is a reference, ignore the reference part.
2. Then pattern-match `expr`'s type against `ParamType` to determine `T`.

For the particular case of:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void g(const T&);

int i = 0;
g(i);
```

1. `i`'s type (`expr`'s type) is `int`.
2. Pattern matching `int` against `const T&` (`ParamType`) determines `T`'s type as `int`.

---

I can try reverse engineering my answer with references to cppreference and The Standard:

1. cppreference: from Eljay's comment [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

- The comment `3) If P is a reference type, the referenced type is used for deduction.` tells you to adjust `P`'s type to `const T`.
- Then you have a detailed example of how deduction works under `1) If P is a reference type, the deduced A (i.e., the type referred to by the reference) can be more cv-qualified than the transformed A:`.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void f(const T& t);
 
bool a = false;
f(a); // P = const T&, adjusted to const T, A = bool:
      // deduced T = bool, deduced A = const bool
      // deduced A is more cv-qualified than A
```

2. The Standard: from [temp.deduct.call/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#call-3): `If P is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of P's type are ignored for type deduction. If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction.`. `Example 3` below that text contains almost exactly your example, apart from the fact that the argument is `const int`.

```cpp
template<class T> int f(const T&);
const int i = 0;
int n2 = f(i);  // calls f<int>(const int&)
```

- `P`'s type is `const T&`.
- Since `P` is a reference type, the type referred to by `P`, i.e. `const T`, is used for type deduction.
- In your example, `A`'s type is `int`. Deducing `T` as `int` would match `P`'s adjusted type as `const int`.

Comment: Can you standardize things out?

Comment: I've tried. Although I continue to prefer Scott's friendliness (he even makes you laugh every other page! :)

Comment: First, _"First, const is ignored for type deduction,"_ this is incorrect, because as stated in: `If P is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of P's type are ignored for type deduction. `  the const here is not top-level const. Second, my second example declares variable `i` as non-const variable

Comment: 1) Why is not top-level const? 2) The non-const `i` is covered in the last bullet of my answer.

Comment: Third, you say nothing about the example you taken from cpprefernce even though it said that `// P = const T&, adjusted to const T, A = bool:` So `P = const T` And `A = bool`; NOW how the deduction is performed

Comment: _1) Why is not top-level const?_ if you have `const int& ref = some_var` Then `const` here is low-level const

Comment: 3) I thought it was quite clear in the example's comments. It says `P = const T&`, `adjusted to const T` (`If P is a reference type, the referenced type is used for deduction.`), then `A = bool`, so `deduced T = bool`, and `deduced A = const bool`.

Comment: OK, you're right about `const` qualifiers not being removed to `P`; that's also what `cppreference` says. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

> Per my knowledge, T cannot be deduced because argument type A requires a qualification conversion to match the parameter type P. **Am I correct to say that?** *This is my first question*.

No, your assumption/understanding that a conversion from `int` to `const int` requires a qualification conversion is incorrect. An example of a qualification conversion would be something like from `int*` to `const int*`.

---

> So it's seemed that the T has been deduced as `int`; why? this is my second question.

This can be understood from [temp.deduct#call-4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-4) which states:

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced A identical to A (after the type A is transformed as described above).
> However, there are three cases that allow a difference:
>
> 4.1) **If the original `P` is a reference type, the deduced `A` (i.e., the type referred to by the reference) can be more cv-qualified than the transformed `A`**.
>
> 4.2) The transformed A can be another pointer or pointer-to-member type that can be converted to the deduced A via a function pointer conversion and/or qualification conversion.

(emphasis mine)

Now we can apply this to your example:

```
template<typename T>
void g(const T&) {};

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    g(i); 
}
```

In above, `P` is `const T&` so it is adjusted to `const T`. And since the passed argument is `A = int`, the deduced `T` will be `int` while the deduced `A` will be `const int`.

---

The same explanation can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

> ```
> template<typename T>
> void f(const T& t);
> bool a = false;
> f(a); // P = const T&, adjusted to const T, A = bool:
>       // deduced T = bool, deduced A = const bool
>      // deduced A is more cv-qualified than A
> ```