# How template argument deduction is performed in this example?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following example:

```
template <class T> 
void f(const T&&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; };

int main(void){

       const int *cptr = nullptr;
       f(std::move(cptr));
}
```

Per [[temp.deduct.call]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-1):

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function
> template parameter type (call it `P`) that contains
> template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction
> with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`)
> [..]

and [[temp.deduct.call]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-3):

> If `P` is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of P's type
> are ignored for type deduction. If `P` is a reference type, the type
> referred to by `P` is used for type deduction.

Considering the given paragraphs, I'm deducing the template argument for `T` to be `int*` as follows:

```
P = const T&&, A = const int*; // replacing 'const T&&' with 'const T'
P = const T, A = const int*
T = int*

// what's wrong with these steps?
```

But when I compile this code with gcc and clang, it shows that the deduced `T` is `const int*`

**My Question**: Why the deduced template argument is `const int*` and not `int*` as I expect?

Comment: There is a top-level const in `P = const T` but there is a low-level const in `A = const int*`. You can't compare them directly that way you did. Here, this means `T` will be deduced as `const int*` and the function parameter will be `const int *const &&`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the definition of \`top-level cv-qualifiers\` in the C++11 Standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676824/where-is-the-definition-of-top-level-cv-qualifiers-in-the-c11-standard)

Comment: @JasonLiam I can understand what you're saying as follows. In `P = const T, A = const int*` the deduction fails because `P` has top-level const and `A` has low-level const. Then the rule [temp.deduct.call#(4.1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-4.1) applies?

Comment: @John Yes, like  similar to explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73338000/12002570).

Comment: @John No, you can compare `P = const T` with `A = int *const` because both of these have top level const. And deduced `T` will be `int*` in this case. Note, i am not talking about this current question but replying to your last comment where you have `A = int* const` instead of `A = coinst int*`. The answer to the current question is given [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73370439/12002570).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the deduced template argument is const int* and not int* as I expect?

The `const` in `P = const T` is a **top level const** and applies to `T` while the `const` in `A = const int*` is a **low-level const** meaning it does not apply to the pointer. This in turn means that you can't directly compare `const T` with `const int*` the way you have done.

Therefore, `T` will be deduced as the simplest argument type `const int*` and the function parameter will be of type `const int *const &&`.

Comment: Am I assuming you mean that `P = const T, A = const int*` **causes** deduction failure, so [alternative deductions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-4) are considered. Right?

Comment: @John In this example, the deduced `A=const int*const` is more cv qualified than the transformed `A=const int*`.

Comment: @John See my updated comment above. I do think that here the the deduced `A=const int*const` is more cv qualified than the transformed `A=const int*`

Comment: _"In this example, the `deduced A=const int*const` is more cv-qualified than the `transformed A=const int*`"_ Therefore, I can compare `P` with the `deduced A` such `P = const T, deduced A = const int *const`, then `deduced T` is `const int*`. Right?

Comment: @John Yes, the problem was that you were comparing them incorrectly which is why i wrote *"can't directly compare `const T` with `const int*` **the way you have done**"* in my answer. That is, yes we can compare but the conclusion that you were getting that `T` should be `int*` instead of `const int*` was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks!. But I just need to understand something. Are the rules of template argument deduction applied once in the P/A pair? I mean, why we can apply the rules again on `P` and `deduced A`?

Comment: .. so `P = const T, deduced A = const int *const`. Per [para 2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-2), since `P` is not of reference type, A's top-level const are ignored, then P's top-level const is ignored per [para 3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#call-3). Therefore we have `P = T, A = const int *` then `deduced T` will be `const int*`

Comment: @John What do you mean by "again". I mean it is the same P/A pair which is just transformed according  to the rules given by the standard like `const T&&` adjusted to `const T` etc. And then at the end of this process(after all the changes/adjustments of the P/A pair) the result is what we use.

Comment: Simply I mean, instead of having this pair: `P = const T, deduced A = const int *const` . I am applying the rules again so that we have instead: `P = T, A = const int *`. That's what I mean by "why we cannot apply the rules again on P and deduced A"

Comment: @John I see, but i don't think that is the case because note that you already have the deduced `A = const int *const` which means you already have the transformed `A = const int*`. There is no need to apply the rules again with `P = T` and `A = const int*`.

Comment: @John I also think that, that whole section describing this deduction process could have been more clearly written/described in the standard.